# 2D Collision in JavaFX - Bad accuracy with .intersects()

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics

I have several Shape objects - `Circle`, `Rectangle` and `Polygon`.

I use the built-in `.intersects(Bounds1, Bounds2)` method to detect collision but it's quite inaccurate.

```
Circle c1 = new Circle(20);
Bounds c1Bounds = c1.getBoundsInParent();
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(20,20);
Bounds r1Bounds = r1.getBoundsInParent();
... etc for other Shape objects
```

My collision code:

```
if (c1Bounds.intersects(r1Bounds) {
    //collision happened.
}
```

Why is the collision accuracy so bad and how can I improve it? The collision detection is REALLY bad for polygon objects. It is literally at least 50 pixels off.

Comment: Check out the answer provided by *jewelsea* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15014709), his code works perfectly fine even with polygons and circles.

Answer (score 2):

`getBoundsInParent()` returns the bounding box around the shape — a rectangle.

The built-in `intersects()` check works only for rectangular shapes, not for circles, polygons, etc. For these, you'd need to implement the check yourself.